# How do I parse Xml in a textarea using python and return json?

Tags: python, json, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to submit a form on a webpage.  The page returns Xml results in a textarea similar to the following:

```
<textarea name='xmlresults' rows='40' cols='150'>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <companies>
   <company name=”Acme Corp” timestamp="2012-09-04 02:49:39">
     <officers>
       <officer name=”John Doe” position=”CEO” />
     </officers>
   </company>
 </companies>
</textarea>
```

I would like to parse the results using python and return a json result.  I am looking for some guidance on the best way to handle this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What failed? We can help you with concrete problems, but you seem to be asking us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict):

```
import xmltodict
import json

json.dumps(xmltodict.parase(txt))
```

But first you to need put quotes in order (there are two types of double quotes in the xml) and remove line with xml version (I don't think you need this in a json result).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The quotes were just because I cut and pasted from Word.  Your solution worked for me.  I had to add .string to the end of my BeautifulSoup parsing.

        text_area = soup.find('textarea', {'name': 'xmlresults'}).string

        json_result = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(text_area))